# Excel: Align by decimal point in cells with stars

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, alignment

In Excel 2011 for Mac, I have the following column of numbers:

```
0.139**
-0.131**
-0.135*
-0.053
0.139**
0.112*
0.183***
```

Some items are negative, and some have stars.

My goal is to have the column formatted so that 1) there are no zeros preceeding the decimal, and 2) the numbers are aligned at their decimal point, like so:

```
 .139**
-.131**
-.135*
-.053
 .139**
 .112*
 .183***
```

After reading a number of other posts on SuperUser, I suspect that I will need to do this from the Format -> Cells -> Custom preference pane, but I have not been successful. Particularly, the cells with stars appear to be immune to formatting. I appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the stars (asterisks) to the numbers with a custom format (eg. 0.000"***") but only for cells containing numbers.

If you have cells containing digits followed by asterisks then Excel treats the cell as text, not as numbers, so you won't be able to apply number custom formats or do arithmetic on them.

I suggest you try to split your numbers and asterisks into adjacent cells (two columns).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will keep trying to find a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can do this with regular custom formatting alone. Conditional Formatting ("CF") can't do it either.

The crux of things is you cannot format for a variable number of a text character after a number (or before, or inside, whatever) using the regular custom formatting functionality unless you can use <, >, =, <=, or >= conditions to define the possibilities. And then, not ore than two. Your asterisks are variable with no obvious rules that can use those conditions. To the outsider's eye anyway. And you need at least three anyway. On the other end of that bar to success is that you cannot format text to line up the decimal points outside of CF.

With CF the problem becomes that it cannot format portions of a thing, just the whole thing. So while it can make a test for applying a rule based upon a portion of a cell's contents (the numerical aspect here), it cannot act on just that portion alone. It cannot format the number part to get the decimal points lined up because only some of the data are simply numerical. So it is of no help.

Let me seem to digress for a moment. If you can use a helper column by the data, or off in some far corner of the spreadsheet (actually, I guess right where the data is, with the data being off in some corner of the spreadsheet), the following formula would do the trick:

```
=IF(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(42),""))>=0,
    TEXT(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(42),""))," #.###")  &  REPT(CHAR(42),LEN(A1)-0-LEN(TEXT(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(42),""))," #.###"))),
    TEXT(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(42),"")),"#.###")  &  REPT(CHAR(42),LEN(A1)-1-LEN(TEXT(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(42),"")),"#.###"))))
```

Sad looking, yes, but its apparent complexity is not for real, plus, it's 2021 now so anyone reading this likely has `LET()` which can make it look far less intimidating.

All it does is:

`Line 1:` Take the numerical value out of the data and learn whether it's positive or negative.
`Line 2:` If it is positive, format the value with the string  `#.###` (note the space at its beginning). This gives it the bump to the right to allow for the negative sign in the negative value data so the decimal points line up.
`Line 3:` And if negative, it formats almost the same, just without the leading space.

And it does one more thing:  it finds the length of the initial strings and subtracts the length of the value strings to find the number of asterisks (`CHAR(42)` so you don't have to "handle" that character in the formula) and uses `REPT()` to add that many asterisks back onto the string produced.

The formula could be "tightened up" by not adding the asterisks in BOTH parts of the `IF()`, but rather concatenate them onto the end after the `IF()` outputs the value. Also, nowadays, one can use a range rather than copying formulas down the column and let `SPILL` handle filling the column.

Lastly, and this is truly sad... lining up the decimal points will not work perfectly unless you use a monospace font. The variable widths of the digits will otherwise ensure the decimal points only mostly line up, and it will almost certainly be pretty apparent. Not hideously so, but probably enough to ruin it for you. This is due to the result above needing to be left justified to let the decimal places line up. If anything else, the fact that each line has (in your sample data) from three to six characters means they simply cannot line up.

I admit, you could complicate the above formula to add a step after it does all the above to pad every value out with some blank characters (like a "space") at the right so all are the same length, but the varying widths of proportional numeral characters will mess that up as much as it would mess up the decimal points, so it might not be incredibly pleasant even after being done. If you want to do it though, I will say this:  every font has some character that is just the right width to space things however you want them spaced. They just aren't all blank characters... but if you can find a font you like with the right blank character available, maybe it would all be good. You know, "if"...

Lastly, to use their values for anything else, you WOULD have to strip out the values like in the formula. So no just saying "=A1". You'd have to strip off the asterisks (and maybe some other characters if you do the work), then use `VALUE()` on the result and put THAT expression everywhere you wanted to draw the values out to. Or make a helper column somewhere, filled with those formulas for the column, that you'd be able to directly refer to instead.

So, last thing. I just have to wonder at the point/use of the asterisks. Best I can come up with is they are meant as footnote markers. If so, or anything similar in nature, you might consider using, say, differently colored values instead. Then the data are all values, not strings, and simple formatting makes them pretty. There's a function from the old Excel 4 Macro language, `GET.CELL()` using parameter 24 for its first argument that one can use in a Named Range (not in a cell) to find a cell's font color and then use the Named Range in cell formulas or CF to use the cell's font color to do things. So it's maybe feasible to do away with the asterisks, especially if data enterers only enter them and then you use their count formulaically to do things... you'd just change how you learn what you need to know.